# How can I provide example data for my request / response in Swagger UI?

Tags: documentation, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm developing one web service with WebAPI 2 and OWIN. My goal is add some documentation with Swashbuckle.

Following my method:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// La mia descrizione...
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">Identificativo</param>
/// <param name="list">Una lista</param>
[HttpPut]
[Route("~/api/v1/documents/{id}/attribute")]
public IHttpActionResult Put(int id, List<AttributeDto> list)
{
    _myService.Create(list, id);
    return Ok();
}
```

Below my **AttributeDto** class code:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace WebApi.Dtos
{
    public class AttributeDto
    {
        [JsonIgnore]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public int OtherId { get; set; }

        public string Label { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If I open Swagger UI I can view one example section with autogenerated data:

[image: Swagger UI autogenerated data example..]

How can I customize autogenerated data so that JSON in picture becomes like below:

```
[
  {
    "label": "Etichetta di esempio",
    "value": "Valore di esempio"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you using [Swagger-Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swagger-Net/) instead of swashbuckle.
All you will need to do is decorate the definition property with an xml example comment like this:

```cs
public class AttributeDto
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public int OtherId { get; set; }

    /// <example>Etichetta di esempio</example>
    public string Label { get; set; }

    /// <example>Valore di esempio</example>
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

This was proposed to swashbuckle but is has not been merge there yet:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/pull/1091
Swagger-Net is my fork of Swashbuckle but I've merged many nice features and fixed many bugs.

Comment: Recommending to use a different tool isn't quite helpful when the question was for a solution for a particular tool.

Answer (score 0):

An option will be to use an ISchemaFilter (that goes on the SwaggerConfig.cs), here is an example:

```cs
private class ApplySchemaVendorExtensions : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, Type type)
    {
        if (schema.properties != null)
        {
            foreach (var p in schema.properties)
            {
                switch (p.Key)
                {
                    case "label":
                        p.Value.example = "Etichetta di esempio";
                        break;
                    case "value":
                        p.Value.example = "Valore di esempio";
                        break;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I personally don't love that solution because we will have to maintain information for a class in two different files...